# Importing a CSV file into an ArcadeDB Docker Container raises a 'Cannot execute command' error on import command execution

Tags: csv, import, graph-databases, docker-container, arcadedb

## What are the details of your problem?

I am trying to import a large dataset into ArcadeDB.
But I'm running into issues with using the `import` example provided.
What is wrong about this ArcadeDB-SQL? How do you well format [ArcadeDB-SQL `import`](https://docs.arcadedb.com/#SQL-Import-Database)?

`Error Message`

```bash
Cannot execute command Error on parsing source 'null'
```

`localhost:2480` AracadeDB-Studio SQL-command

```sql
import database file:///home/arcadedb/icij-offshoreleaks-44-fixed.csv with forceDatabaseCreate = true, commitEvery = 1000
```

## What did you try and what were you expecting?

### I tried

1. Creating ArcadeDB following [ArcadeDB.com](https://arcadedb.com/)'s instructions

   1. Only editing to be detached rather than cleanup so I can continue using afterwards

   ```bash
   docker run --d -p 12480:2480 -p 12424:2424 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Darcadedb.server.rootPassword=playwithdata -Darcadedb.server.defaultDatabases=Imported[root]{import:https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz}" arcadedata/arcadedb:latest
   ```
2. Copy file onto [ArcadeDB's Docker-container](https://hub.docker.com/r/arcadedata/arcadedb)

   ```bash
   docker cp /file/location/filename.csv arcadedb:/home/arcadedb
   ```
3. Open to [`localhost:12480`](http://localhost:12480/)
4. Type-in import-command

   ```
   import database file:///home/arcadedb/filename.csv with forceDatabaseCreate = true, commitEvery = 1000
   ```

### I expected

The file would start importing, but instead saw the webpage notification of

```bash
Cannot execute command Error on parsing source 'null'
```

Any help would be appreciated where I might've missed a step or didn't format the `import` statement correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to move the CSV file under ArcadeDB's server path and use a local path (not absolute)? Example: `import database file://icij-offshoreleaks-44-fixed.csv with forceDatabaseCreate = true, commitEvery = 1000`

Comment: Yes, I have. still getting the same error.